# Remote desktop solution which works with port 80

Tags: remote-desktop, firewall, port, remote-access

The corporate firewall where I work won't allow any programs to access any ports other than 80.

This is a real bummer because when I try to remote in to external machines, using either LogMeIn.com or TeamViewer, both of them seem to need to use ports other than 80.

Why can't they just stick with port 80? Why do they have to use other ports, even when I'm using the browser-based version of their product (e.g. TeamViewer Web Connect)?

So anyway, is there a trick to get around this issue, or are there any alternate remote desktop products that will let me use only port 80?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to connect to a small number of computers, you could install an ssh server on each, then forward the ports required by LogMeIn and TeamViewer through an ssh tunnel through port 80. Search for ssh tunneling and port forwarding.

Comment: You don't need one on each, you only need 1 SSH server behind NAT for all of them, and use ssh port forwarding through the SSH port, which could be 80.  It is presumed the OP is allowed 443 but needs it for browsing. nothing wrong with RDP here either. They can all stay 3389, it is the IP that is switched.  I'll allow this over 10 years later.

Answer (score 1):

In our corporate environment we use [Techinline](http://www.techinline.com) which only uses the standard HTTPS port (443) and doesn't require any other configuration whatsoever. It's entirely browser-based so you shouldn't encounter any issues as with Teamviewer or LogMeIn.

Comment: But the poster specifically said port 80. All others are unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/index.html)?

If your server/pc is behind router you can create a forwarding rule to transfer trafic from port 80 to 5900 as vnc server listens on 5900.

Answer (score -1):

I am too late for this answer, but Chrome Remote Desktop works on Port 443 HTTPS
see this link for more detail: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop